# How to update Table When you have List of field Names With JOOQ

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I have list of field names, I would like to generate update query.

I tried following way it's working, but I have to cast it to TableField every time. Is there any better way?

```kotlin
DSL.using(DefaultConfiguration()).update(JOB)
.set( JOB.field("id") as TableField<Record, Any>, 123)
.where(JOB.ID.ge(0)).sql
```

**Note:** I am using JOOQ 3.8 version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just reference `JOB.ID` again:

```kotlin
DSL.using(DefaultConfiguration())
   .update(JOB)
   .set(JOB.ID, 123)
   .where(JOB.ID.ge(0))
   .sql
```

Comment: Right now i am using this way. But the  major problem for me is column names and it's values will be determined @ run time.  So static reference won't help me here. ex: hash map contains column names and it's values.

Comment: @NagarajuNooka: But that was not your question :-) Please can you ask a new question that expresses the runtime problem you're trying to solve *explicitly*?

Comment: oh ok, i wll do that.